# Apache server - Unable to locate CSS and JS files

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, proxypass

I want that when i hit URL A, it should serve content from URL B but the URL on the address bar should keep pointing to URL A only.

```
URL A: http://apps.company.com/lab
URL B: http://svrdev-73:6020
```

To try this out, in `hosts` file, i have configured the following:

```
172.16.0.73         apps.company.com
```

I am using Windows server 2016. Application B and Apache (`ver. 2.4`), both are running on same Windows server. I found that `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` might help.

Added the following lines at the end of `httpd.conf` file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Proxy http://svrdev-73:6020/*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass         /lab  http://svrdev-73:6020 nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /lab  http://svrdev-73:6020
```

After (mis)configuring, when i  try hitting URL A, though it takes me to the login page that comes up when i directly access URL B, but when i login, it doesn't display anything. In console section of my browser, i see the following:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.00e8fde0.css:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.aa149470.js:1
```

When i check the Apache log, i see this:

```
[Sun Sep 23 12:35:54.949711 2018] [core:info] [pid 20708:tid 1072] [client 172.16.0.73:60914] AH00128: File does not exist: C:/apache24/htdocs/static/css/main.00e8fde0.css, referer: http://apps.company.com/lab
[Sun Sep 23 12:35:54.949711 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20708:tid 1076] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 172.16.0.73:60913] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://apps.company.com/lab
```

From the above i see that it is looking for file in the default `DocumentRoot` directory (i.e., `"${SRVROOT}/htdocs"`) however, my application code (URL B) is in Tomcat at `c:\app-tomcat\webapps\ROOT\` directory. I also tried changing the DocumentRoot dir path to `c:/app-tomcat/webapps/ROOT` where *index.html* resides along with *static* dir and other files but i am still getting the same error. I also changed this property `<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">` to `<Directory "c:/app-tomcat/webapps/ROOT">` but the error persists. No other modifications were done to the `httpd.conf` or any other file in Apache except for changing the log level and enabling `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` module.

Any idea how i can resolve this?

Comment: It always helps if while down-voting you can comment as well so i can improve on it. Not everyone is comfortable working in all areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only redirect `/lab`, but the static files are not in `/lab`, they are in `/static`.

So you should also redirect `/static` so that these files can be accessed.

Another way would be to just place the static files into the appropriate Apache directory.

**Edit**

The error message about file not found says

```
C:/apache24/htdocs/static/css/main.00e8fde0.css
```

Assuming The `DocumentRoot` is `C:/apache24/htdocs` that means the URL to access the file is `/static/css/main.00e8fde0.css`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether i have explained it using the right terms but what i want to say is that the website is `company.com` and what i want is if i hit URL A i.e., `http://apps.company.com/lab`, it should take me to URL B. I have not created any dir called `lab` under `${SRVROOT}/htdocs`. All code is present in `c:/app-tomcat/webapps/ROOT` path. Under this path, there is index.html, `static` dir. `static` dir further contains `css` and `js` directories. I want _everything_ to be served from URL B.

Comment: But your `ProxyPass` says `/lab` and not `/`. So how is `/static` supposed to end up at your URL B?

Comment: Apologies for my lack of understanding. I have not used Apache really but given the query i have and the clarification i mentioned in my comment, is there no way i can use `http://apps.company.com/lab` and access URL B without moving any `static` content to Apache's dir? When you said, redirecting `/static`, do i need to add two extra lines for `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`?

Comment: I don't know enough about your setup to answer that. But you may try `/` instead of `/lab`.

Comment: I think this is what you meant, correct? Added `ProxyPass  /static  http://svrdev-73:6020/static nocanon` line and this one, `ProxyPassReverse  /static  http://svrdev-73:6020/static`. Though i am getting some errors in browser's console section, i can see the page contents. :)

Comment: Also, in your answer, when you said `but the static files are not in /lab, they are in /static`, did you mean to say that the static files are not lying `directly` in parallel with `index.html` file but instead in a sub-dir named `static`? Is that the reason i had to handle `static` separately? Is there a way `/static` can be clubbed with `/lab` so i can have only one line each for `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`?